# Angular.js http GET request, CORS issue while sending cookies

Tags: node.js, angularjs, http, cors

I'm working on a project using node.js and express.js on server side, and angular.js on client side. I've set up authentication on server side using passport.js. So when I login the session cookie is set up and I can access the api via browser with no problem. But when I try to request the url of the api in angular.js with http, I get "cors blocked" (yeah, I made that up). Server allows credentials, client sends withCredentials: true. What is the problem?

Funny thing is server and client are not even in different domains. They are both in localhost. But since server "cors blocked" me in the very beginning, I've enabled cors.

So I have server and client in the same domain. Corse is enabled in server and I still can't send my cookies.

```
Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    *
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  33101
Content-Type    application/json
Date    Sun, 18 May 2014 15:02:41 GMT
Etag    "-796401813"
X-Powered-By    Express
access-control-allow-cred...    true
Request Headers
Accept  application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Cookie  prgck=s%3AGb1ZXuD0uXHoBbFWIcrmkSFt.%2BNt0pdVa1%2BNhUNITAPOzPjmQxklPpDrdvQz%2BACj084o
Host    localhost:1212
Origin  http://localhost:8000
Referer http://localhost:8000/app/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0
```

Comment: The reason it is a CORS request is because of different ports. It's not just the hostname/domain that can cause this.

Comment: It may also be worth posting the relevant Express code you're using.

Comment: There isn't much on the Express code. It's a simple route that sends data from mongodb. It works fine with authentication if I reach the api via browser (e.g. localhost/api/get). If I turn off withCredentials in angular http request, I get 401 as expected. If I disable authentication everything works perfect. So the "cors block" only happens if I try to send cookies with the request.

Comment: How are you using the `cors` middleware? Are you simply using the defaults with `app.use(cors());` or are you specifying options or ?

Comment: Also, is the http request you've shown above an OPTIONS or other type of request?

Comment: It is a GET request and I am using cors({credentials: True}).

Comment: The number of additional questions, the failed answering attempts and your lack of will to update your own answer with more details (particularly code) make of this question a good example of what you should not do if you want to get a good set of interesting answers.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you did on your Express server, but looking at the headers you posted it seems you enabled Access-Control-Allow-Credentials but you did not define the Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

This latter is necessary to actually enable CORS. So your Express server must set both:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://my.domain.com:8080
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true;
```

Comment: As I stated in above comments; normally, everything works fine between the client and the server. The cors error happens only if I turn on withCredientials on the client side. I am using cors middleware [here](https://www.npmjs.org/package/cors) to allow cross domain requests.